# How to Customize Error Pages Template In symfony 3.1?

Tags: symfony, error-handling

I am using Symfony 3.1. I did follow below url for implementing the custom error page template.

**(http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#custom-exception-controller).**

I creates all files under the same location:

```
app/
└─ Resources/
   └─ TwigBundle/
      └─ views/
         └─ Exception/
            ├─ error404.html.twig
            ├─ error403.html.twig
            ├─ error.html.twig      # All other HTML errors (including 500)
            ├─ error404.json.twig
            ├─ error403.json.twig
            └─ error.json.twig      # All other JSON errors (including 500)
```

I did create a bundle with name "TwigBundle" and create controller folder and class with name **"TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController.php"**

**Config.yml**

## Twig Configuration

```
twig:    
    exception_controller:  TwigBundle:ExceptionController:showException
```

**error.html.twig**

```
    <h1>Page not found</h1>

    {% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
        {# ... #}
    {% endif %}

    <p>
        The requested page couldn't be located. Checkout for any URL
        misspelling or <a href="{{ path('homepage') }}">return to the homepage</a>.
    </p>

In case you need them, the Ex
```

i am getting following error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException' in D:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECT_NAME\var\cache\prod\appProdUrlMatcher.php:922 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECT_NAME\var\cache\prod\classes.php(1744): appProdUrlMatcher->match('/jkhjjkohuioioi...') #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECT_NAME\var\cache\prod\classes.php(1613): Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher->matchRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECT_NAME\var\cache\prod\classes.php(2758): Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->matchRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #3 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher)) #4 D:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECT_NAME\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener.php(61): call_user_func(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\ in D:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECT_NAME\var\cache\prod\classes.php on line 3328
```

I have clear the cache and system is running  in Prod ENV.
But still i am not getting custom error template.

Comment: Did you just create the custom templates or did you configure a custom error controller? What specific steps did you perform?

Comment: I just create custom template at above mention  location . noting to do for controller

Comment: did u added `@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml` into your dev routing file? You do not need to rewrite default exception controller.

Comment: Okay @Stephan Yamilov can you provide full example ?

Answer (score 1):

**In first**, you need to create new errors templates into this location:
`/YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER/app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/`

For sample, let create one: **error.html.twig** for handle all errors

**In second** you must write some template content for your errors views.
For the experiment, let put this content into our error.html.twig:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Error test. An Error Occurred: {{ status_text }}</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>WooHoo! Now you can see new error template</h1>
<h2>The server returned a "{{ status_code }} {{ status_text }}".</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**In third**, let check this error in dev environment. To do this put this route into your dev route file `/YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER/app/config/routing_dev.yml` (it can be there already)

```
# app/config/routing_dev.yml
_errors:
    resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
    prefix:   /_error
```

After adding this route, let's check our new error template. go to this link in your web browser:

`/app_dev.php/_error/418` where is `418` is just error status code

If you see new error template in develop environment it will be the same on prod env too. Do not forget to clear cache if you want to check it on production environment.

Note that you can create template `error404.html.twig` for handle only 404 errors. Or you can create `error500.xml.twig` for xml reponse of 500 error.

Comment: can u paste profiler route info, when enter this route `/app_dev.php/_error/418` in your dev environment? Like this: http://joxi.ru/5mdoo7YudvLor1

Comment: Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 FatalErrorException in classes.php line 2031: Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler

    in classes.php line 2031

Comment: in  app/config/routing_dev.yml
errors.xml, i did not have any errors.xml file

Comment: I hope you remove `twig: exception_controller:` parameter from config file?

Comment: I removed. Now i have only:

twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

Comment: When i try to run the url with not exist action then i am expecting it will give me error404.html.twig but its showing


Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /asdfasdf/"" at D:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECT_NAME\var\cache\dev\classes.php line 2774

Comment: Did u use apache2 or nginx as web server? ur project on `localhost/project` path? it's seems that problem in it.

Comment: It is on apache i am using vhost for accessing my project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126734/discussion-between-stephan-yamilov-and-ashish-kumar-saxena).

Answer (score 0):

For me, this is what works flawlessly. Might not be how the docs recommend but its simple to understand. You can try it as an alternative.

\app\Resources\TwigBundle\views\Exception\error.html.twig

```
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}An Error Occurred: {{ status_text }}{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

    {% if status_code >= 500 %}
        {# twig include 500s server error template here #}
    {% elseif status_code >= 400 %}
        {# twig include 400s user errors template here #}
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Whats the outcome, same fatal error or something else?

Comment: when i run this one: http://localhost/project/app_dev.php/_error/418

output: 


Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 FatalErrorException in classes.php line 2031: Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler

    in classes.php line 2031

Comment: The solution I wrote for you doesn't require creating a new bundle, controller or service, which can be a bit complicated when your starting out. (temporarily) remove your customizations and drop the above file as is in the stated directory and see that it works

Comment: I think I've found your problem, you are mixing 2 methods in 1. The link you gave to the symfony docs lists options 1,2 or 3 NOT steps 1,2 and 3. So simply delete twig: exception_controller:  TwigBundle:ExceptionController:showException and everything will work.

Comment: Okay, if i trying to run this url          http://localhost/projectname/abc                        abc action doest not exit then it will show custom template. which is not displaying.                  its showing     No route found for "GET /abc"
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
1 linked Exception:

    ResourceNotFoundException »