# How to customize error pages Symfony?

Tags: exception, error-handling, symfony, custom-error-pages

I followed the instructions on the page https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-error-templates and have created my own errors templates to display error pages depending on status code of the error (i.e. `error.html.twig` contains `{{status_code}}` variable):

```
|-- app/
    |-- Resources/
        |-- TwigBundle/
            |-- views/
                |-- Exception/
                    |-- error.html.twig
                    |-- exception.html.twig
```

But:

1. pages error.html.twig and exception.html.twig never shown, no matter what env is set.
2. in the production environment I can see fatal errors and every kind of Symfony Exceptions which it should never take place - yet it is prod env! (**edit:** The problem only occurs on my local machine - on remote server I see just default browser's error pages)

How to fix this? I found only 1 similar topic at stack ([How to Customize Error Pages Template In symfony 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257640/how-to-customize-error-pages-template-in-symfony-3-1)) but it doesn't contain the right answer.

Comment: did you try remove cache folder ?

Comment: Yeah, did it a lot of times

Comment: I guess it's all about my cache issue. My problem has disappeared two days after creating this thread. My application caches responses when it seems to have caching disabled. It's very frustrating for me because, for example I upload some files through FTP (on production) and I can't see these changes! And what is the strangest - the `var` directory is totally empty! Do you know what could cause this problem?

Comment: Maybe the opcache extension is enabled and `opcache.validate_timestamps` ini settting is set to `Off`.